# How to make custom type (string) marshal CDATA format in golang?

Tags: xml, go, cdata

WeChat message reply requires such a format, CDATA is to resolve the special characters.

```
<xml>
<ToUserName><![CDATA[toUser]]></ToUserName>
<FromUserName><![CDATA[fromUser]]></FromUserName>
<CreateTime>12345678</CreateTime>
<MsgType><![CDATA[text]]></MsgType>
<Content><![CDATA[hello world]]></Content>
</xml>
```

When using `golang` to achieve the specification,I found that the  xml.Marshal () can be used with the struct tag `xml:",cdata"` .
Define a struct to deal with, the codes seems like:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TextMsg struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"xml"`
    ToUserName   CDATA
    FromUserName CDATA
    CreateTime   int64
    MsgType      CDATA
    Content      CDATA
}

type CDATA struct {
    Text string `xml:",cdata"`
}

func main() {
    msg := TextMsg{
        ToUserName:   CDATA{"userId"},
        FromUserName: CDATA{"appId"},
        CreateTime:   time.Now().Unix(),
        MsgType:      CDATA{"text"},
        Content:      CDATA{"some message like <hello>"}}

    b, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "    ")
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

> Output results:

```
<xml>
    <ToUserName><![CDATA[userId]]></ToUserName>
    <FromUserName><![CDATA[appId]]></FromUserName>
    <CreateTime>1485837083</CreateTime>
    <MsgType><![CDATA[text]]></MsgType>
    <Content><![CDATA[some message like <hello>]]></Content>
</xml>
```

But I think it's not perfect, since variable assignment is not as convenient as the normal string type, so I change the CDATA into string type, and try to achieve MarshalXML ():

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TextMsg struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"xml"`
    ToUserName   CDATA
    FromUserName CDATA
    CreateTime   int64
    MsgType      CDATA
    Content      CDATA
}

type CDATA string

func (c CDATA) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    e.EncodeElement("<![CDATA["+string(c)+"]]>", start)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    msg := TextMsg{
        ToUserName:   "userId",
        FromUserName: "appId",
        CreateTime:   time.Now().Unix(),
        MsgType:      "text",
        Content:      "some message like <hello>"}

    b, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "    ")
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

> But the output results do not meet expectations, "<" or ">" is
>   escaped:

```
<xml>
    <ToUserName>&lt;![CDATA[userId]]&gt;</ToUserName>
    <FromUserName>&lt;![CDATA[appId]]&gt;</FromUserName>
    <CreateTime>1485837470</CreateTime>
    <MsgType>&lt;![CDATA[text]]&gt;</MsgType>
    <Content>&lt;![CDATA[some message like &lt;hello&gt;]]&gt;</Content>
</xml>
```

Do you have any good suggestions for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another structure `CDATA2` which has tag `xml:",cdata"`, and pass it to `EncodeElement()`.

`EncodeElement()` would correctly encode `CDATA2{"foo<>"}` to `<![CDATA[foo<>]]>`.

```
type CDATA2 struct {
    Text string `xml:",cdata"`
}

func (c CDATA) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    e.EncodeElement(CDATA2{string(c)}, start)
    return nil
}
```

Check it in: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_w2uiniuQb)

**Edit**: you can use anonymous struct if you don't want to define named type

```
func (c CDATA) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    e.EncodeElement(struct {
        string `xml:",cdata"`
    }{string(c)}, start)
    return nil
}
```

Check it in: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WlAFhIRrQ8)

Comment: thank you very much！it's really a good idea.I changed the code so that the extra structure would not be exported: `func (c CDATA) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
 return e.EncodeElement(struct {
  string "xml:\",cdata\""
 }{string(c)}, start)
}`

Comment: @woylyn You're welcome. Since your code seems much smarter. I would edit the answer.